# C# sql INSERT INTO Throwing Exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Thank you in advance for any help that you may have to offer. I am currently building a program with Visual Studio 2015 and am trying to write a method that will perform an `INSERT INTO` a table that I have already established.

When I run my code I get

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll"

exception message in my console. I am very new to SQL so any basic principles and advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void InsertIntoAccount(int number, string type, string date)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //Establish a connection
        connection1.Open();
        string sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Account (AccountNumber, Type, DateOpened) VALUES (@number, @type, @date)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, connection1);

        //Fill in parameters
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = number;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = type;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = date;

        //Execute
        //<REMOVED> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection1.Close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Any inner exception?

Comment: What are the `SQL`data types of the columns `AccountNumber, Type and DateOpened`

Comment: Im sorry, but can you be more specific? during runtime that is the only exception that occures. On a side note, (a lingering area of concern) i think my connection string is proper because I have a working username/password form in visual studio that will open and close a test connection
EDIT: account number is a int and the other two are strings

Comment: @DavidBell when debugging with Visual Studio, you can always inspect the Exception and look at the `inner exception`, where most of the time the real information is provided

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Also with your **DateOpened** field, is that of type varchar or is that of type date/datetime

if it is of type date/datetime try to convert your string to a date object and then change the line to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date, 100).Value = date;
```

Comment: Questions should be asked as comments, not as part of your "answer"

Comment: yeah unfortunately to do that i would need 2 more reputation points, so as an attempt to answer the question, i have also tried to ask questions that would allow OP to go back and look at the data structure

Comment: Im quite new to visual studio so I appreciate you all bearing with me here. I did notice that in the 'events' section it gives more information on the error. It writes "Invalid Object name "Account" inside the exception parameters. However upon inspecting my diagram, from which visual studio generated the SQL to make the tables, that the name is in fact Account. thanks again

Comment: The name might be Account, but it could be created in a schema.  Did you check the fully qualified name?

Comment: Like Hogans said, check which schema the Account table was created under. By default it's `dbo`, which depending on your access settings to the database, you might have to access as `dbo.Account` instead of just `Account`

Comment: Yeah very true. When i do it i do the full qualification <databasename>.dbo.<tablename>

Comment: Took a break for dinner, I will inspect the inner exception, thank you very much for your help. I will explore all of your solutions and be back soon!

Comment: UPDATE: I checked the generated SQL and it is in fact Accounts with an s instead of Account like on the ER diagram. I attempted to do an insert after explicitly describing the databaseName.dbo.Accounts, and I did get an error. However I have found the source of the error. 
     Off the top of my head it was something like "Cannot set SIN to null.." after looking at my ER diagram SIN is a foreign key gathered from Client whos primary key is SIN. I assume it is giving me trouble because when im doing my insert I am not adding in who the account belongs to. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database data types are correct. You have a date field, yet you are assigning a value with the data type VARCHAR. Try change your 3rd parameter declaration to something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that your connection string value is incorrect. The error means there is no table `Account` in DB that your are specifying using connection string.

In you example, your passing a string value as connection string, assuming you have defined it somewhere in code.

Connection string :

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
```

Password=myPassword;

Example :

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=True;"
```

Crosscheck this variable. The initial catalog should be the database name.

A better approach could be to read the connection string from `web.config`.

```
SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString)
```